# Problems using merge_all from the 'reshape' package in R

Tags: r, list, merge, reshape

I have a variable `d.merg.hosp.aucs.list` which contains 100 `lists` each containing 8 integer values. I want to perform `quantile()` on all of these values so I did:

> d.merg.hosp.aucs.list <- merge_all(d.merg.hosp.aucs)

`merge_all` being a built-in function from the `reshape` package. However, after I finished running that code, I checked to see if all the lists merged

`>d.merg.hosp.aucs.list` but I got this:

`data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows`

Where did I go wrong?

Here's a reproducible example of the first 10 lists in the `d.merg.hosp.aucs`:

> d.merg.hosp.aucs <- list(c(0.666666666666667, 0.238095238095238, 0.666666666666667,0.666666666666667, 0.541666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.416666666666667,0.25), c(0.428571428571429, 0.476190476190476, 0.642857142857143,0.571428571428571, 0.541666666666667, 0.833333333333333, 0.333333333333333,0.777777777777778), c(0.714285714285714, 0, 0.428571428571429,0.595238095238095, 0.666666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 0.583333333333333,0.444444444444444), c(0.619047619047619, 0.714285714285714, 0.571428571428571,0.928571428571428, 0.5, 0.541666666666667, 0.333333333333333,0.333333333333333), c(0.523809523809524, 0.619047619047619, 0.428571428571428,0.571428571428571, 0.25, 0.583333333333333, 0.583333333333333,0.5), c(0.285714285714286, 0.380952380952381, 0.0952380952380953,0.904761904761905, 0.416666666666667, 0.541666666666667, 0.583333333333333,0.388888888888889), c(0.19047619047619, 0.523809523809524, 0.380952380952381,0.523809523809524, 0.9375, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 1), c(0.428571428571429,0.619047619047619, 0.428571428571429, 0.80952380952381, 0.75,0.666666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 0.111111111111111), c(0.80952380952381,0.523809523809524, 0.571428571428571, 0.571428571428571, 0.416666666666667,0.645833333333333, 0.458333333333333, 0.722222222222222), c(0.80952380952381,0.666666666666667, 0.428571428571429, 0.452380952380952, 0.458333333333333,0.583333333333333, 0.458333333333333, 0.388888888888889))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a list of vectors, not data.frames.  If I understand correctly, you want to combine all the values into a single vector to pass to quantile().  You can just `unlist` it into a numeric vector.

```
quantile(unlist(d.merg.hosp.aucs))
       0%       25%       50%       75%      100% 
0.0000000 0.4166667 0.5327381 0.6510417 1.0000000
```